# DIV element is displayed surprisingly out of its expected place

Tags: html, css

I am relatively new to HTML and CSS and now I have a problem, which I cannot even properly name, thus I did research, but found nothing useful.

```css
html, body{
 height: 100%;
}
#divsContainer {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background: lightgray;
}
#leftDiv {
 width: 60%;
 height: 100%;
 background: lightblue;
 display: inline-block;
}
#rightDiv {
 width: 30%;
 height: 100%;
 background: lightgreen;
 display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="testStyles.css">
  <script>
   function f(mess) {
    console.log(mess + " hello click");
   }
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="divsContainer">
  <div id="leftDiv">
   <p>This is left DIV</p>
  </div>
  <div id="rightDiv">
   <p>This is right DIV, users:</p>
   <ul>
    <li> User One </li>
    <li> User Two </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

As you can see, left `<div>` element is displayed, but not right on top of the page. Why does it happen? I didn't specify any `float` or `position`, didn't use any `padding` and other spacing. Other `<div>` is displayed as expected... Why there is a difference?

After understanding why does it behaves that way, I hope I'll be able to figure it out, but I am also open to suggestions how to fix that.

**EDIT** It is due to right `<div>` being bigger, but why one depeneds on the other? I hoped that both will be displayed independently

Comment: Because inline block alignment defaults to `baseline`.

Comment: @Paulie_D How baseline is determined? How to fix it then? This is first time I come upon such term

Comment: vertical-align:top or overflow:hidden to the elements

Comment: added another duplicate with full details